Botocore.exceptions.DataNotFoundError: unable to load data points for : glue
I’m working on migrating aws glue etls from v2 to v4.
While creating glue client i’m getting error botocore.exception data not found: unable to load data points error.
Failing at botocore—> loaders.py —> data_load_with_paths
Client = boto3.client(“glue”)

Versions I’m using are:
Botocore & boto3 == 1.43.142
Awscli == 1.33.22
Same botocore function was available in gluev2 and was working fine.
Please share your suggestions
Tried adding different versions if boto3 and botocore.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
